Multiplication of a matrix by sub-matrices
I have a $J \times J$ matrix $C$ that is upper triangular. Also, $C'C$ is positive definite. I also have a matrix $A$ formed by submatrices of size $J \times K$ as follows
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3 \\ \vdots \\ A_N \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A_i = [I_{J \times J}\  B_{i_{J \times (K - J)}}]$ for each $I$. I create a new matrix $A_{new}$ such that
$$
A_\textit{new} = \begin{bmatrix} CA_1 \\ CA_2 \\ CA_3 \\ \vdots \\ CA_N \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Notice that $A_\textit{new}$ can be written as
$$
A_\textit{new} = \begin{bmatrix} C & CB_1 \\ C & CB_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ C & CB_N \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Is there a way for me to write $A_\textit{new}'\cdot A_\textit{new}$ in terms of matrix operations or concatenations?
I have a loop where I need to obtain a matrix $A_\textit{new}$ for different values of $C$. This is extremely costly computationally as the matrices $B_i$ and $C$ are huge. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Write $Q=C'C$.  Then $Q$ is a perfectly arbitrary positive definite  martrix.  Your target matrix breaks up into blocks of the form $\pmatrix{Q&QB_i\cr B_i'Q&B_i'QB_i\cr}$ where the $B_i$ are perfectly arbitrary.  So it seems like your problem is equivalent to the problem of finding a fast way to compute $QB,B'Q$ and $B'QB$ where $Q$ is positive definite and otherwise $B$ and $Q$ are perfectly arbitrary.

Hi @StevenLandsburg. Thank you for checking my question. That is correct. $A_{new}'A_{new} = \begin{bmatrix} NQ& \sum_i QB_i \ \sum_i B_i'Q & \sum_i B_i'QB_i \end{bmatrix}$. However, In this case the computation of the right lower block is computationally costly. Specially because in my case N is around 170k, K is 176 and J = 146.
